# how do I use a class when I only find out its name in a string variable at run time?

Tags: java, class

Is there a way to run class X's methods from another class (in the same project but different package) when I only have class X's name stored in a String - say I don't know what classes exist until my program starts and I scan the directory for .java files then store those names into Strings.

So for example I have class A, which has functions 'main' and 'method1' - my program gets the name of class A from its file into String s. Then I want to be able to run the main or method1 functions but am unsure how to manipulate s to get there...one thing I've tried is this but I simply get the Exception error and don't know if it's on the right track, any suggestions?:

```
//gets the filename from JFileChooser method_fc
File file = method_fc.getSelectedFile();

try {
   Class c = Class.forName(file.getName());
   Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("main");
   Object instance = c.newInstance ();
   Object result = method.invoke(instance);
} catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Cannot access class: "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Suggestion 1: Post the full exception, not just "I simply get the Exception error".

Comment: first guess: strip the .java or .class from the filename...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`main` is usually a `static` method with a `String[]` parameter. If so, you don't need an instance - use the Class object itself as the target object.

This fragment works on a standard `main` method:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.company.SomeClass");
Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
method.invoke(c, (Object) new String[] {});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for what I wanted to do. Thanks to the other replies too, all the info's given me a better picture of how it works - sorry for not specifying, yes my main method is static, receives a String array as parameter, and doesn't return a value

Answer (score 2):

You can do that but take into consideration that class name does not end with ".java" or ".class" (you can remove it).

Answer (score 2):

My *guess* is that your `main` method has a `String[]` parameter, but you're not supplying it - or it's a static method, but you're trying to call it as an instance method.

However, it's hard to tell without seeing with the class *or* the error message.

As Fernando notes, the name of the class isn't the same as the name of the file - not only would a filename end in ".class", but there might also be packages involved - a file "Foo.class" may actually contain a class "com.acme.Foo".

EDIT: As noted in comments, the class will also need to be in the classpath, or a special `ClassLoader` will be required.

Comment: Also worthy to note is that the class should be in the classpath.  Going from this code example, the user could select any classfile on the system.

Answer (score 0):

please report the full stack of the exception.

I guess that your main method receive as parameter at least an array of string. Furthermore the main method usually doesn't return any result because it is defined as void.
Why didn't you pass args to the method invoke?

```
String[] args = new String[1]
Object result = method.invoke(instance, args);
```

Please report at least the declaration of the main method.

Regards,
Luca